# How to get the blocks between timestamp

Tags: web3js

I want to take the blocks between give timestamps. currently I manually use

```
fromBlock: (await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()) - 12343
toBlock: (await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()) - 6172
```

For getting yesterday's blocks. Is there any way to get the blocks using `web3` between the timestamps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the blocks between `timestamp1 <= block.timestamp <= timestamp2`, you can do a binary search:

- over the highest `fromBlock` you can find that satisfies `web3.eth.getBlock(fromBlock).timestamp <= timestamp1`
- over the smallest `toBlock` you can find that satisfies `timestamp2 <= web3.eth.getBlock(fromBlock).timestamp`

Then, depending on your Web3 version, you do:

- v0.20.x: a [web3.eth.filter({ fromBlock, toBlock }).get(console.log)](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#returns-48)
- or v1.0 [web3.eth.getPastLogs({ fromBlock, toBlock }).then(console.log)](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs)

Answer (score 4):

In case you need a binary search implementation, here it's for Python 3:

```py
web3 = Web3(WebsocketProvider("...."))
a = 1484362538 # 01/14/2017 @ 2:55am (UTC)


def estimate_block_height_by_timestamp(timestamp):
    block_found = False
    last_block_number = 9682416
    close_in_seconds = 600

    while not block_found:
        block = web3.eth.getBlock(last_block_number)
        block_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(block.timestamp).date()
        difference_in_seconds = int((timestamp - block_time).total_seconds())

        block_found = abs(difference_in_seconds) < close_in_seconds

        if block_found:
            return last_block_number

        if difference_in_seconds < 0:
            last_block_number //= 2
        else:
            last_block_number = int(last_block_number * 1.5) + 1


block = estimate_block_height_by_timestamp(
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a).date()
)

print(block)

>>> 2994181
# https://etherscan.io/block/2994181
# Block time - Jan-14-2017 11:21:00 AM +UTC
```

Comment: It may be possible to use the fact that 1 block always takes ~x seconds to perform a much faster search...

Answer (score 2):

It's actually possible to use the fact that block-times are locally roughly linearly separated to optimize well beyond a binary search.

This code typically requires 5 or fewer fetches to find the nearest block to a given unix timestamp, and benchmarks ~10x faster than a binary search:

```py
import  arrow

T = lambda i_block: web3.eth.getBlock(i_block).timestamp

ilatest = web3.eth.get_block('latest')['number']

def iblock_near(tunix_s, ipre=1, ipost=ilatest):
    ipre = max(1, ipre)
    ipost = min(ilatest, ipost)

    if ipre == ipost:
        print('Got it')
        return ipre

    t0, t1 = T(ipre), T(ipost)

    av_block_time = (t1 - t0) / (ipost-ipre)

    # if block-times were evenly-spaced, get expected block number
    k = (tunix_s - t0) / (t1-t0)
    iexpected = int(ipre + k * (ipost - ipre))

    # get the ACTUAL time for that block
    texpected = T(iexpected)

    # use the discrepancy to improve our guess
    est_nblocks_from_expected_to_target = int((tunix_s - texpected) / av_block_time)
    iexpected_adj = iexpected + est_nblocks_from_expected_to_target

    print()
    print(f'target timestamp ({tunix_s}) lies {k:.3f} of the way from block# {ipre} (t={t0}) to block# {ipost} (t={t1})')
    print(f'Expected block# assuming linearity: {iexpected} (t={texpected})')
    print('Expected nblocks required to reach target (again assuming linearity):', est_nblocks_from_expected_to_target)
    print('New guess at block #:', iexpected_adj)

    r = abs(est_nblocks_from_expected_to_target)

    return iblock_near(tunix_s, iexpected_adj - r, iexpected_adj + r)
```

Test:

```py
import arrow

tunix_s = arrow.get('2021-03-11T12:34:56').timestamp()

block = iblock_near(tunix_s)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pi's response is pretty good. But, I've ran into rare situations where the +r/-r excludes tunix_s, and then it recurses until recursion depth limit exceeded. These adjustments fix that issue:

```py
def iblock_near(tunix_s, left_block_tuple=(1, web3.eth.get_block(1).timestamp), right_block_tuple=(latest_block_number, web3.eth.get_block('latest').timestamp)):
    left_block = left_block_tuple[0]
    right_block = right_block_tuple[0]
    left_timestamp = left_block_tuple[1]
    right_timestamp = right_block_tuple[1]

    if left_block == right_block:
        return left_block
    # Return the closer one, if we're already between blocks
    if left_block == right_block - 1 or tunix_s <= left_timestamp or tunix_s >= right_timestamp:
        return left_block if abs(tunix_s - left_block_tuple[1]) < abs(tunix_s - right_block_tuple[1]) else right_block

    # K is how far inbetween left and right we're expected to be
    k = (tunix_s - left_timestamp) / (right_timestamp - left_timestamp)
    # We bound, to ensure logarithmic time even when guesses aren't great
    k = min(max(k, 0.05), 0.95)
    # We get the expected block number from K
    expected_block = round(left_block + k * (right_block - left_block))
    # Make sure to make some progress
    expected_block = min(max(expected_block, left_block + 1), right_block - 1)

    # Get the actual timestamp for that block
    expected_block_timestamp = web3.eth.get_block(expected_block).timestamp

    # Adjust bound using our estimated block
    if expected_block_timestamp < tunix_s:
        left_block = expected_block
        left_timestamp = expected_block_timestamp
    elif expected_block_timestamp > tunix_s:
        right_block = expected_block
        right_timestamp = expected_block_timestamp
    else:
        # Return the perfect match
        return expected_block

    # Recurse using tightened bounds
    return iblock_near(tunix_s, (left_block, left_timestamp), (right_block, right_timestamp))
```

This modified version, caches the timestamp of 1 and latest, enforces logarithmic time convergence, and is thus safer to use and makes fewer requests as well.

tunix_s will also clamp to 1 or latest, if tunix_s is out-of-bounds for the eth network.